# Getting an error while defining route in play framework

Tags: playframework

I have below GET request,which is defined in the routes file,but when this request is hit,Play framework throws an error "Identifier expected".

GET   /company/users/_mapping/field/*

Any idea how to define this request in the routes file ?

Comment: Can you add the complete line of your route configuration and corresponding Action signature.

Comment: GET /company/users/_mapping/field/*

controllers.ESController.fieldMappings

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly ? The '*' in your route indicates a parameter that will be bound by Play and passed to your controller. If you use this, you *have to* define its name and pass it to your controller. ex : `GET /company/users/_mapping/field/*param  controllers.ESController.fieldMappings(param)`

Comment: Actually this worked.Thanks a lot!
GET /company/users/_mapping/field/*param
controllers.ESController.fieldMappings(param)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After declaring the method in this way,did solve the problem.
GET /company/users/_mapping/field/*param controllers.ESController.fieldMappings(param)